How can I symlink to a pre-existing folder and maintain its connection to a GitHub repository?
I am one of two users collaborating on a website. We use a shared GitHub repository for version control.
The website is served from /shared/WWW. Initially, User 1 was given a symlinked /user1/WWW directory, which they could easily populate with the contents from the GitHub repository, as both directories were empty to start. Updating the website contents for User 1 is as simple as running cd /user1/WWW && git pull.
Now, User 1 may not continue maintaining the website regularly, and I (User 2) will take over. I want a directory /user2/WWW that has the same functionality as User 1's: it should be synchronized with /shared/WWW and connected to the GitHub repository via my credentials.
However, I face two issues:

If I (User 2) create the symlink first, I don't know how to connect the non-empty directory (/shared/WWW, populated by User 1) to the existing GitHub repository via something like git clone.
If I clone the repository first, I don't know how to symlink the non-empty /user2/WWW to /shared/WWW.

What is the best way to set things up so that both User 1 and User 2 can git pull with their respective credentials while sharing access to a synchronized /shared/WWW directory?

So, if I understand correctly, shared/WWW is a symlink to user1/WWW and you want to change that to be symlink to user2/WWW instead? If so, just redo the link and commit that change: rm shared/WWW will remove the old link, ln -s user2/WWW shared/WWW (mind your /user2 vs user2: make it just like you had before for user1--in your question you've shown it with and without the slash!). Then git commit shared/WWW and git push and now whatever worked for user1 should start working for user2. But your question is not super clear, so this is at best a guess at an answer.

I edited things slightly for clarity, but no, that's not what I'm asking. I don't want to change the symlink from User 1 to User 2 -- I want both users to have access to shared/WWW (via a symlink to personal directories or otherwise), and I want both users to be able to git pull with their respective credentials to populate the contents of shared/WWW.

So, in effect, there is really only one live folder, /shared/WWW, which contains a cloned sandbox. While you can easily symlink that account into user2's home with ln -s /shared/WWW /user2/WWW, I guess the problem you find is that the files belong to the wrong user? More clarifications, is /shared/WWW the actual live deployment of the web site? If so, it's unusual to deploy as a sandbox.

More commonly, you would have a sandbox in your home directory, and copy the files using a deployment script. Each user with deploy access would have their own, independent sandboxes, which you can update with your usual process, and when you're happy with the contents of the web site, run the deploy script which copies all the files to the live website path.
